# How do I connect the dots to get a polygon in JAVA?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, polygon, graphics2d

I'm making an application for creating convex
polygon.

I imagined it to be so that I first set the vertices of the polygon and then create it.

I was able to make the addition of points (vertices). Now I need help connecting the dots with a line.

This is what it looks like:
[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJdrm.png)

And I would like when I click the Draw Polygon button that these points connect and it looks like a polygon, like this:
[and it should look like this when I click the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y72FP.png)

Here's the code so you can run it yourself:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

public class MyPaint{
    
    public static void main(String[] args){    
        
        final PadDraw drawPad = new PadDraw();     

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw Polygon");  
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        ((JComponent) contentPane).setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, null, null));
        contentPane.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        JButton buttonDrawPolygon = new JButton("Draw Polygon");
        buttonPanel.add(buttonDrawPolygon);
        
        JButton buttonReset = new JButton("Reset");
        buttonPanel.add(buttonReset);
        
        contentPane.add(drawPad, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
    }
}


class PadDraw extends JComponent{

    private Image image;    
    private Graphics2D graphics2D;  
    private int currentX , currentY , oldX , oldY ;
    
    public PadDraw(){
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            oldX = e.getX();
            oldY = e.getY();
        }
    });
    
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            currentX = e.getX();
            currentY = e.getY();
            if(graphics2D != null) {
                graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
                repaint();
                oldX = currentX;
                oldY = currentY;
            }
            System.out.println(oldX + " " + oldY);
        }
    });
    
}   
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    if(image == null){
        image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
        graphics2D = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphics2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
    }
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Collect your points in a list. When you draw in the paintComponent() method, draw your points and then connect them.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer I can already draw points like in the picture, but how can I use a list of points to connect them? What function could I use to connect them?

Comment: `Graphics2D` has a lot of drawing  methods, check its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) (don't forget its parent class)

Comment: There's even a polygon shape. Use it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Introduction

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Here's your revised GUI

[image: Start]

Here's the GUI with four points

[image: Points]

Here's the GUI with a polygon

[image: Polygon]

I'm not showing it, but the Reset button clears the drawing area.

## Explanation

When I create a Swing GUI, I use the [model-view-controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.  This pattern allows me to separate my concerns and focus on one part of the Swing application at a time.

A Swing application model consists of one or more plain Java getter/setter classes.

A Swing view consists of a `JFrame` and one or more `JPanels`.

Swing controllers are the listeners that are attached to `JButtons` and drawing `JPanels`.

### Model

For this application, I created a `PolygonModel` class.  The class holds a `boolean` that tells me whether or not to draw the polygon and a `java.util.List` of `java.awt.Point` instances.  The `Point` class holds an X and Y `int` value.

### View

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I broke up your `main` method into a couple of methods.  I separate the creation of the `JFrame` from the creation of the `JPanels`.  This allows me to separate my concerns and focus on one part of the GUI at a time.

The `JFrame` methods must be called in a specific order.  This is the order I use for most of my Swing applications.

I changed your `PadDraw` class to extend a `JPanel`.  I moved the `MouseAdapter` code to its own class.  Your drawing panel should draw.  Period.  Nothing else.

The `paintComponent` method always starts with a call to the `super.paintComponent` method.  This maintains the Swing paint chain and helps to eliminate unwanted drawing artifacts.

The drawing `JPanel` is cleared before every repaint.  Therefore, you have to completely redraw your image each time.  That's why we store the `List` of `Point` instances in the model.

### Controller

I created three controller classes.

The `PointListener` class extends `MouseAdapter`.  Notice how simple the `mousePressed` method becomes with an application model.

The two `JButtons` each have their own `ActionListener`.  Since they are so simple, I made each of them lambdas.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the additional classes inner classes so I could make them public and post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

public class PolygonImage implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new PolygonImage());
    }

    private final PolygonModel model;

    private final PadDraw drawPad;

    public PolygonImage() {
        this.model = new PolygonModel();
        this.drawPad = new PadDraw(this, model);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw Polygon");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(drawPad, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel
                .setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, null, null));

        JButton buttonDrawPolygon = new JButton("Draw Polygon");
        buttonDrawPolygon.addActionListener(event -> {
            model.setConnectPoints(true);
            repaint();
        });
        buttonPanel.add(buttonDrawPolygon);

        JButton buttonReset = new JButton("Reset");
        buttonReset.addActionListener(event -> {
            model.setConnectPoints(false);
            model.clearList();
            repaint();
        });
        buttonPanel.add(buttonReset);

        return buttonPanel;
    }

    public void repaint() {
        drawPad.repaint();
    }

    public class PadDraw extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private final PolygonModel model;

        public PadDraw(PolygonImage view, PolygonModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            this.addMouseListener(new PointListener(view, model));
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 300));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setColor(Color.black);

            // Draw points
            for (Point p : model.getPoints()) {
                int radius = 6;
                int diameter = radius + radius;
                g2d.fillOval(p.x - radius, p.y - radius, diameter, diameter);
            }

            // Draw polygon
            if (model.isConnectPoints()) {
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
                List<Point> points = model.getPoints();
                if (points.size() >= 1) {
                    Point old = points.get(0);
                    for (int index = 1; index < points.size(); index++) {
                        Point p = points.get(index);
                        g2d.drawLine(old.x, old.y, p.x, p.y);
                        old = p;
                    }
                    Point p = points.get(0);
                    g2d.drawLine(p.x, p.y, old.x, old.y);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class PointListener extends MouseAdapter {

        private final PolygonImage view;

        private final PolygonModel model;

        public PointListener(PolygonImage view, PolygonModel model) {
            this.view = view;
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            model.addPoint(event.getPoint());
            view.repaint();
        }
    }

    public class PolygonModel {

        private boolean connectPoints;

        private final List<Point> points;

        public PolygonModel() {
            this.points = new ArrayList<>();
            this.connectPoints = false;
        }

        public void setConnectPoints(boolean connectPoints) {
            this.connectPoints = connectPoints;
        }

        public boolean isConnectPoints() {
            return connectPoints;
        }

        public void clearList() {
            this.points.clear();
        }

        public void addPoint(Point point) {
            this.points.add(point);
        }

        public List<Point> getPoints() {
            return points;
        }

    }

}
```